# UWP Xaml rotate checkbox trims label

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I am trying to put checkboxes horizontally next to each other. Since I have lots of them, I want the labels to be vertically. The issue is that the application measures the width of wisible part of the label and then rotates it (I guess), and therefore just a small part of label is rendered. I find Xaml quite confusing and since this is just "stupid" static view, I would like to define it in Xaml, not implementing any rendering classes.

I rotate the Checkbox with the following code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

And I want to display them like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[0], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" Content="Buffer A min" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[1], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" Content="Buffer A max" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[2], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2" Content="Buffer B min" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[3], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="3" Content="Buffer B max" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[4], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="4" Content="Pallete too high" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[5], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="5" Content="Pallete ok" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[6], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="6" Content="Pallete down" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[7], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="7" Content="Pallete up" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[8], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="8" Content="Pallete button" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[9], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="9" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[10], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[11], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="11" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[12], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="12" Content="Pallete ok 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[13], Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="13" Content="Pallete too high 2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

In the picture provided, you can see the result - checkbox has some width, but only the part visible prior to the rotation is rendered in the rotated result. Any ideas please?

[image: rotated checkbox]

Comment: Has your problem been resolved? Please feel free to cantact us if you have any concerns.

Comment: Hello. Actually no, the checkboxes should display GPIO status for IoT project and since the result doesnt have display attached, I didn't want to spend unnecessary time on it, that's why I didnt accept @mm8 's answer. Also, I believe this has to have solution without installing additional nugets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WPF there is a `LayoutTransform` property that applies the transformation when *layout* is performed.

There is no such property in UWP but you could use the `LayoutTransformControl` from the [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/) NuGet package:

```
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls">
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="controls:LayoutTransformControl">
            <Setter Property="Transform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Page.Resources>
    ...
    <controls:LayoutTransformControl Grid.Column="1">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Bind (x:Boolean)DataModel.Moxa3InData[1], Mode=OneWay}" Content="Buffer A max" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </controls:LayoutTransformControl>
    ...
```

Comment: @Klemikaze: Did you try this?

Comment: Hello. Actually no, the checkboxes should display GPIO status for IoT project and since the result doesnt have display attached, I didn't want to spend unnecessary time on it.